# HOW TO POST IMAGE FILE WITH ALAMOFIRE 5.5

Tags: swift, post, alamofire, multipartform-data, multipart

i want to **POST** an image file with multipartform using alamofire 5.5
im success to implement the **GET** method with this recently alamofire but get stuck with the **POST** method.

TIA

Comment: What was the problem with the POST method that made you get stuck?

Comment: @mkrieger1 i mean i  dont know the latest code for it, because it cant be works with the older code for the older alamofire

Answer (score 2):

For Uploading images to server we need to use multipart request, you can upload the image to a server by using the following code snippet.

```
 func uploadImage(imgType:String,imgData:Data,imageName:String){
    // params to send additional data, for eg. AccessToken or userUserId
    let params = ["userID":"userId","accessToken":"your accessToken"]
    print(params)
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
        for (key,keyValue) in params{
            if let keyData = keyValue.data(using: .utf8){
                multiPart.append(keyData, withName: key)
            }
        }
        
        multiPart.append(imgData, withName: "key",fileName: imageName,mimeType: "image/*")
    }, to: "Your URL",headers: []).responseJSON { apiResponse in
        
        switch apiResponse.result{
        case .success(_):
            let apiDictionary = apiResponse.value as? [String:Any]
            print("apiResponse --- \(apiDictionary)")
        case .failure(_):
            print("got an error")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping, so the params is like the headers?

Comment: The params variable is not header they are additional data, for example if you want to update the username, email and profile picture by using same endpoint at that point you can use it. If you just want to update a photo than params is not needed. If you want to define headers there is a separate parameter in AF.upload() method called "headers" which is list of http headers, you can use it for sending headers. Please feel free to ask if you didn't get it.

Comment: okay, i want to use headers, so the rest of code just same like your comment above? just add the headers in multipart.append is it right?

Comment: and the fileName is the string of imgData?

Comment: Yes, there is a header parameter in AF.upload() method. Just add it and you are good to go.